# Loop through widths of elements and show elements until a certain width is meet

Tags: jquery

I have a list of logos (static) and a page header (this changes) on the same line. I want to dynamically fit the logos (too many to show in the space) in the left over space that page header has not taken.

Approach:

- hide logos first

1.) leftoverSpace = containerWdith - pageheaderWidth
2.) loop through each logos width
3.) Once the 'leftoverSpace' number is hit the looping stops.

This is what i got so far: Its not correct but I trying.

```
var pageheaderWidth = null;
brandsbannerWidth = null;
pageheaderWidth = $(".page_header h1").width()
pageheaderWidth = pageheaderWidth + 40;    

brandsWidth = (960-pageheaderWidth)-10

$(".brands_banner li").each (function(index) {

brandsbannerWidth = $(this).width();

if(brandsbannerWidth == brandsWidth) 

$(this).show();

});
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code it is really hard to provide a good answer.

I would say you need something like this:

```
var logos = $('.logos');

logos.hide();

$.each(logos, function () {

    var containerWidth = ...//define your variable here
    var pageheaderWidth = ...//define your variable here

    leftoverSpace = containerWidth - pageheaderWidth

    if (leftoverSpace == yourThresholdHere) {
         return false;
    }

    $(this).show();
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Looking at your edit now:

```
var pageheaderWidth = $(".page_header h1").width() + 40 //no need to declare it previously 
var brandsWidth = (960-pageheaderWidth)-10

$(".brands_banner li").each (function(index) {
      (condition here)
});
```

Comment: How do I hide those specific elements at that particular width?

Comment: well, i think it s better that you hide them all first (see my code) and then in the loop you start showing one by one unless the condition inside the if statement is met (leftoverSpace == yourThresholdHere). When this condition is met the loop stops, thus leaving the rest of the items hidden :)

Comment: write your code in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) and save it. Then post me the link here and i will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple overflow:hidden does it correctly. I had some notion that the overflow wouldn't hide the the whole element, just a part of it.